# SQL, возвратить удаленные строки

Tags: sql, jdbc

Как должен выглядеть запрос в котором удаленные строки возвращаются клиенту, возвращение строк с их последующим удалением в одном запросе? Использую jdbc.

Comment: jdbc это драйвер. А то что вы хотите должна уметь СУБД. Например postgresql это делает с использованием предложения RETURNING. А например MySQL этого не умеет в принципе

Comment: Mike, а можете привести пример, если не сложно

Comment: `delete from table where ... returning id`

Comment: https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/dml-returning.html

Comment: @Mike MySql умеет вернуть кол-во удаленных строк.

Comment: @Tsyklop количество удаленных возвращают все БД, это стандартная функция. А вот сами строки ...

Comment: В стандарте SQL нет такой возможности, поддерживаемой всеми или большинством СУБД. Отредактируйте вопросу, указав СУБД (желательно и а тегах тоже)